# Custom readonly_fields and has_delete_permission on Django admin TabularInline

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have an `admin.TabularInline`.

I need to configure dinamically readonly_fields and I need to enable or disable deleting with `has_delete_permission` checking some fields in current object. Is possible this?

What have I check in this method ?

```
def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
```

Where can I found che current saved object (not parent object)?

Comment: `has_delete_permission` checks if the currently logged in user has the permission to delete any instance of the model. Django does not do anything with `obj` and a permission system on object level isn't implemented by default. You can override this method if you want and add your own logic. `obj` is the object that is going to be deleted.

Comment: @dirkgroten yes, but in obj i see the parent object not the obj model associated to TabularInline admin.

Comment: If you define this method inside the `InlineModelAdmin` subclass you should see the inline object. Of course, inside the parent's `ModelAdmin` you see the parent.

Comment: Alas, inside the `InlineModelAdmin`, `obj` is the parent, not the inline item.